# paypal subscribe monthly option and buy now full price in one button call

Tags: api, button, paypal, payment, subscriptions

I have looked through the docs of paypal's api and cant find and option that will allow me to have a user click on a buy now button on my site and when they land on the paypal payment screen be presented with two ways to pay.

1. Either a monthly cost of $25. subscription model.
2. One time yearly payment of $300. non-subscription model.

Has anyone done this or could point me in the right direction. Ideally i want the select options to live on the paypal side not my website's side.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this some more here is what i found:

2 options:
- Create two buttons with each values. 1 reoccurring and 1 flat rate. 
- Create a button with drop-down code that has two reoccurring payment options. You need to have a drop-down on your site for them to select and pass that option to PayPal. The only downside to this is that they both seem to have to be reoccurring and cant be different types.